# HTML: put text on the center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put text in the center. Vertically its in the middle but horizontally not. What am I missing? Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LqxdR/3/)

```
<div style="display: table; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;text-align: center">

    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
                              text-align: center;" class="dlgImg">this is text</div>

</div>
```

Comment: use margin property of CSS to perform this.

Comment: give width:100% to outer div

Comment: set width 100% to both divs will solve your problem. have a look at my answer to get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<div style="display: table; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;text-align: center;width:100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;" class="dlgImg">this is text</div>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X4Ng4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
        <div style="display: table; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;text-align: center;margin:auto">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;margin:auto" class="dlgImg">this is text</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that your both divs should be 100% width. make it to 100% and it will solve your problem.

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LqxdR/5/)</kbd>

Add `Width:100%` will solve your problem as shown below :

```
<div style="display: table;width:100%; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;text-align: center">

    <div style="display: table-cell;width:100%; vertical-align: middle;
                              text-align: center;" class="dlgImg">this is text</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `width` for the div. Everything would be fine after you add the width to either one or both of the div(s).

Answer (score 1):

Added `width:100%;` to first div

```
<div style="display: table; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;text-align: center; width:100%;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;" class="dlgImg">this is text</div>
</div>
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/LqxdR/4/)

Answer (score 1):

give width:100% or how much the width you want to first div

```
<div style="display: table; width:100%;height: 600px; overflow: hidden;text-align: center">

    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
                              text-align: center;" class="dlgImg">this is text</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you notice you have `div` inside the `div`

your setup like this:

```
<div class="imgContainer">
  <div>
    <div>
          /* text here */
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you give exact width in your `div.imgContainer` `width:800px;` and the next child `div width:600px;` in `inline` style but you don't give width in `div` where the text belong.

try this solution hope this help

```
.imgContainer div{
    width:100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/LqxdR/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Your vertical alignment is functioning because you have set `height` of the `table`.

`style="display: table; height: 600px;` .

Your horizontal alignment will function if you provide `width` for table

`style="display:table;height:600px;width:100%;"`